# Getting TextField String into another Class' String variable with Button Click

Tags: android, android-intent, textfield

I have a class which contains two text fields and a button. How can I get the textfield data into another class' variable, and display that in the new class' activity.

My NewProductActivity class with two textfields and a button;

```
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {


// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
Button button1;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://XXX";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    strName = inputName.getText().toString();


        btnNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching create new product activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Custom.class);
                    i.putExtra("STRING_VALUE", strName);       
            startActivity(i);

        }

       });
```

What should I include into the onClick method to take the two textfield variables of this class and assign them into two String variables inside the Custom class?

I haven't written anything anything into the Custom class yet, could you give me an example of the Custom class like;

```
public class Custom extends Activity{

TextView tw;
String urString;
Bundle extras;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras == null) {
           urString= null;
        } else {
            urString= extras.getString("STRING_VALUE");
        }     
    } else {
        urString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_VALUE");
    }
    tw=new TextView(this); 
    tw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tw); 
    tw.setText(urString);

}


private final Runnable mUpdateUITimerTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do whatever you want to change here, like:
        tw.setText(urString);
    }
};
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look [here for official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

You need to use `putExtra` method when starting intent and `getExtras` from Bundle in another Activity

Example from [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");
```

and in second activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    return;
    }
// Get data via the key
String value1 = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
if (value1 != null) {
  // do something with the data
}
```

EDIT:

I realized it just now, you should have this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` where android:name is name of your package and class

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.stackoverflow.Custom"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_custom" >
</activity>
```

Now in your class where you want to insert values

```
private EditText inputName;
private EditText inputPrice;
private Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    // Launching create new product activity
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Custom.class);
        i.putExtra("Name", inputName.getText().toString());     
        i.putExtra("Price", inputPrice.getText().toString());

        startActivity(i);
        //Finish activity where values were inserted if you dont want to come back with back button
        finish();
    }
});
```

And in class where you want to retrieve values

```
public class Custom extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
        String price = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Price");
        tv.setText(name + " " + price);
}
```

Of course I create custom.xml layout but it is just TextView showing your values

Comment: Can you demonstrate it on the code I've provided above? What is Value1? is it something like Value1 = textfield.getText().toString()?

Comment: value is the name , you can choose whatever you want, and second value is the value you want to put in there , so in your case it would be i.putExtra("inputName",inputName.getText().toString()); and in second activity Bundle extras.getString("inputName"); that should work, let me know if you have any problems with that I am just writing it in comment, I did not test it.

Comment: I edited the answer so it works now, if you are happy with it, accept it as correct and happy coding.

Comment: HI @raklar , does everything works as it should? You did not respond to your question, just curious..

Answer (score 1):

To pass the value:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
i.putExtra("STRING_VALUE", strName);
```

To retrieve try something like:

```
String urString;

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras == null) {
       urString= null;
    } else {
        urString= extras.getString("STRING_VALUE");
    }     
} else {
    urString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_VALUE");
}
```

Comment: Show the method please.  Its onCreate where you pull out the value.  also show the startactivity statement.  Upvoted.

Comment: startActivity(i); You can put the statements in onCreate() if you'd like to pass the value as soon as the activity starts. You can also attach it to an event, i.e. button click

Comment: Just updated my question with your guidance but I don't get any text displayed on the Custom class, however if I change this line, bottom of onCreate; tw.setText(urString);   to   tw.setText("AAAA");    It displays AAAA